# Google Cloud ML Engine: Hyperparameter Tuning Fails to Load Tensorflow Backend

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-ml

I'm using Cloud ML Engine to tune my model's hyperparameters.  I'm looking at the logs it produces and I see an `Error` that says:

`Using Tensorflow Backend`

It says the severity is `Error` and this is the `jsonPayload`:

```
 jsonPayload: {
  created:  1536552469.856194   
  levelname:  "ERROR"   
  lineno:  326   
  message:  "Using TensorFlow backend."   
  pathname:  "/runcloudml.py"   
 }
```

I'm using a Keras model with a Theano backend but I do import Tensorflow in my `train` function.

The logs, unfortunately, don't provide much additional detail.  Any idea why ML Engine would have trouble using Tensorflow?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the log you posted comes from [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/backend/__init__.py#L88). It doesn't indicate a real error. If your job failed, it should be caused by other issues. And you can send your project number as well as job id to `cloudml-feedback@google.com` if you get trouble to debug it.